# Unusual segment LCD technology

Tags: lcd

I've been doing some research on old-school segment LCD displays for a project I'm working on and came across this video:

https://youtu.be/jLew3Dd3IBA?t=40

At the 40-second mark the YouTuber starts showing some unusual colour segment displays where the colour appears to be in the liquid crystal itself:

[image: orange LCD]

Then on another it looks to be that the background is coloured and the liquid crystal is silver when active - note the shadow of the segments on the blue underneath:

[image: Blue LCD]

These both appear to be TN (Twisted Nematic) LCD displays but have been able to achieve an opaque colour rather than the standard black (so just stopping light passing) that TN displays are known for.

These are not CSTN (color super-twisted nematic), CCSTN (color coded super-twisted nematic), or color passive matrix - as far as I can tell.

So my question is does anyone know what this technique/technology is called?

Comment: Can you provide a specific question? It's a little unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a supplier that offers "Color Polarized Film Sheets":

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/0-Degree-Glossy-Red-Blue-Golden_60746416552.html

Answer (score 1):

The second image looks really interesting indeed. But for the first display I have a guess. It looks like a standard negative LCD display with orange instead of black coating.

[image]

Since they have a close-up image we can see its shadow, so if you look closely to the inverted display watch also you can see the shadow. Of course it depends on the distance between the LCD and back panel.

For second image, It is very interesting and I could not find any similar displays. Hope we can get an answer from other people. I am really curious.

Comment: Both the orange and blue examples are "negative," but I'd love to know how they are doing the colours. The choice of black on silver for most LCD displays has to do with the technology itself - when a segment is activated the display is actually blocking light - hence the black. The silver background is for reflectivity.

Comment: I came across with some Chinese companies that produces custom LCD displays so that you can choose lots of colors, designs and technologies. So, it is probably not that hard to implement in these days.

Comment: Probably not hard, but I can't find any examples. There are plenty of companies that do custom LCDs but I haven't found one yet that offers this specific technique. The custom colours are always for the blacklight.